# Python Django как генерировать html страницу для статей

Tags: python, html, django, веб-программирование

делаю сайт на фв Django. Необходимо было сделать возможность добавления статей в блог. Блоки статей создаются, но необходимо также сделать чтобы в этом блоке была кнопка, при нажатии на которую открывается отдельный html файл конкретной статьи. Как я понимаю для этого нужно при каждом создании статьи генерировать для этого отдельный html. (Впрочем допускаю что это не так). Вопрос в том, как собственно генерировать эти html-ки с текстом каждой статьи, либо есть ли какие-то более адекватные решения?

Файлы:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Articles
from .forms import ArticlesForm
def blog_home(request):
    blogs=Articles.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/blog_home.html', {'blogs': blogs})

def create(request):
    err=''
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = ArticlesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('blog_home')
        else:
            err='Wrong Form'

    form=ArticlesForm()

    data = {
        'form': form,
        'error': err
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/create.html', data)
```

create.html (Страница с формой для создания статей):

```
{% extends 'main/layout.html' %}
{% block name %}Create blog{% endblock %}
{% load static %}
{% block text %}
<body style="background-image: url('{% static 'main/img/body/phon-micro.png' %}');background-size: cover;
  min-height:890px;background-repeat: no-repeat;">
<div class = "blogfeatures">

    <h1>Create blog</h1>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.title }}<br>
        {{ form.text }}<br>
        <span>{{ error }}</span>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Сохранить</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

blog_home.html (Страница где отображаются сами блоки):

```
{% extends 'main/layout.html' %}
{% block name %}BLOG{% endblock %}
{% load static %}
{% block text %}
<body style="background-image: url('{% static 'main/img/body/phon-micro.png' %}');background-size: cover;
  min-height:890px;background-repeat: no-repeat;">
<div class = "blogfeatures">

    <h1>Блог</h1>
    <a href="{% url 'create' %}"><li><button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Добавить статью</button></li></a>
    {% if blogs %}
        {% for el in blogs %}
            <div class="alert alert-warning">
                <h3>{{ el.title }}</h3>
                <p>{{ el.text }}</p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <p>Нет статей</p>
    {% endif %}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Генерация html для статей ничем не отличается от генерации каких угодно страниц для каких угодно моделей. Пройдите какой-нибудь туториал по основам django, в любом из них это подробно описано (очень странно, что вы уже умеете создавать формы, но до сих пор не умеете создавать страницы для моделей)

Comment: Вот даже в официальной документации https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial03/